# What does the provided regexp match?

Tags: java, regex

I've got a regex but I'm not sure what the `{1,}` stands for. Full regex is next: `^.{1,}$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^.{1,}$` matches strings that have **atleast one** of any(non-newline) character.

It is effectively same as: `^.+$`

The general form of this limiting quantifier is:

`{min,max}` which means minimum of `min` repetitions but not more than `max` repetitions.

You can drop the `max` part thereby specifying only the lower limit on the number of repetitions and no bound on the upper limit: `{min,}`

In your case `{1,}` means one or more repetitions.

Answer (score 1):

`{1,}` is the same as `+` Which means 1 or more occurences

Answer (score 0):

It means any character at least one time.

- `{1}` exactly one time
- `{1,3}` between one and three times
- `{1,}` at least one time

Answer (score 0):

It stands for "one or more". The whole expression means "the beginning of a line (`^`) with one or more (`{1,}`) of any character (`.`) on it through end of the line (`$`)". [Details here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), but the `{n,m}` syntax lets you specify *exactly* what range of matches you want to find. For instance, `aj{2,4}` would match an "a" followed by 2-4 "j"s, so it would match "ajj", "ajjj", and "ajjjj" but not "aj" (too few "j"s).

Answer (score 0):

`{1,}` means: match at least once. The general syntax is: `{n,}` - match `n` or more times. It is documented [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 0):

at least one or more than one
it's the same as the `+` - operator

Answer (score 0):

It means match repetitions of the previous character (i.e. any character) at least 1 time. It will basically match non-empty strings.